# To get the souce code of the function

Tags: r

I would like to know the source code of the function writtingin R.
below is the fucntion `bondprc(p = 100, r = .05, ttm = 5, y = 0.05)`
i want to know the code of this function, please advise is there any available fucntion, any library containing that fucntion.

I am trying `showmethods()`, `getmethods()`, but not working.

please advise.

Comment: You can press F2 to see the source code of a function when the cursor is over it in RStudio. Also, searching bondprc brings up this [Datacamp course](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/bond-valuation-and-analysis-in-r/introduction-and-plain-vanilla-bond-valuation?ex=10)

Comment: type function name without `()` also prints the function code.